# Extension of Progress Bar causing warning of not key value-coding compilant

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, warnings, uiprogressview

I set up an extension to change the height of a progress bar:

```
extension UIProgressView {
    @IBInspectable var barHeight : CGFloat {
        get {
            return transform.d * 2.0
        }
        set {
            // 2.0 Refers to the default height of 2
            let heightScale = newValue / 2.0
            let c = center
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, heightScale)
            center = c
        }
    }
}
```

and then set the height using this of the progress bars in viewDidLoad()

```
EncounteredBar.barHeight = 10
```

And then eventually got the warning:

> 2016-12-19 22:04:02.249 CYOA[1169:17032] Failed to set (barHeight) user defined inspected property on (UIProgressView): [<UIProgressView 0x7f834bd520d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key barHeight.

The annoying part is even when I remove the extension and the setting of barHeight from the code, this warning still appears. I would like to know how to get rid of this warning.

Comment: It looks like you have tried to set a property `barHeight` in your storyboard scene. This won't work.

Comment: Oh I see that now, do extensions auto add that? Is there a way I can get rid of it?

Comment: No, you must have added it in the identity inspector tab in IB for the progress bar

Comment: Ah I see it, thank you